# rotating log files based on time with java util

Tags: java, logging, file-io, java.util.logging

```
Handler h = new FileHandler("../logs/ParserProcess.log",FILE_SIZE, 20, true);
```

the above achieve logging rolling based on file size limit defined. I would like to know how to rotate logs per run. Can this be achieved without log4j, if so how.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this in the past. What you could do is cutstom name the file depending on the current date/time. Comsider the java classes "Calendar" or "SimpleDateFormat" to get you started. With the date format you can indicate how you want your file to be named each time you open a Handler, or a BufferedWriter, or you can use Calendar to check the date, and only write to a log for "Today" or "This month". I hope this is useful to you! :)

SimpleDateFormat: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
Calendar: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Answer (score 0):

## Logging Framework

A decent logging framework should do this for you.

For an overview of logging frameworks, see this other [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21690610/642706) to another question.

For example, see the [RollingFileAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) in the [LogBack](http://logback.qos.ch/) framework which you access via the [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) façade API.

Answer (score 0):

Your title for this question asks about rotating by time but the body of this question asks about rotation by run.

If you want to trigger a file rotation by run or by time then don't use the append option and then open and close the file handler.

> Handler h = new FileHandler("../logs/ParserProcess.log",FILE_SIZE, 20, false);

If each 'run' is the lifetime of the JVM process then this is supported out of the box.